# Func Invoke, is there a better solution

Tags: c#, lambda, func, control-flow

I've an async downloader class that I want to control with different settings from a service layer.

In the downloader class I've the following setup to control how the downloads should be handled.
Don't mind the monitor etc. keep focus on the Invoker :)

```
public Func<CompletionParams, bool> CompletionQuery { get; set; }

        public class CompletionParams
        {
            public int ItemsToDownload { get; set; }
            public long TimeoutInMilliseconds { get; set; }
        }
```

//some other stuff goes here

```
 while (!this.CompletionQuery.Invoke(new CompletionParams { ItemsToDownload = items.Count(), TimeoutInMilliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds }))
                lock (this.waitForMe)
                    Monitor.Wait(waitForMe, 250);
```

I then configure my downloader in the service layer with something like:

```
downloaderFoo.CompletionQuery = limit => 
                limit.ItemsToDownload >= 22 || limit.TimeoutInMilliseconds > 2000;
```

But the thing i don't like about this is that the while loop uses .Invoke

Is there a better way to use the versatile lambda expression for controlling the flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to lose lambda in the `while` without losing the versatility of specifying a custom completion query delegate.  You are using a delegate to store code, to call a delegate you have to do an Invoke.

If on the other hand you just do not like the `.Invoke` portion of your code, just remove it:

`while (!this.CompletionQuery(new CompletionParams { ItemsToDownload = items.Count(), TimeoutInMilliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds }))`

But as has been pointed out in comments, this will still do an Invoke underneath.